# LDAP breaks after upgrading to stream

Tags: centos, ldap, sssd

so I just started upgrading all of our centos 8 servers to centos stream and the first one seemed to go pretty smoothly with just these commands:

```
dnf install centos-release-stream

dnf swap centos-{linux,stream}-repos

dnf distro-sync
```

but then when I tried to log in with my AD creds it wouldn't let me in. I already tried rejoining the domain and making sure my creds are still good. The only error is in the messages log which says:
`Credentials cache I/O operation failed` I found something that says it's because the cache files don't exist in /tmp so I copied them over from one of my other servers but still no luck. No other errors or anything useful in other log files just incorrect password logs in secure. I was just wondering if anyone else has run into this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
systemctl stop sssd-kcm
rm /var/lib/sss/secrets/*
systemctl start sssd-kcm
```